# Stuck with suffix notation, kronecker delta.

Tags: vector-analysis

To help me understand, I will try to type down two examples where I dont understand how it possibly can be like that, first of all, $d_{ij}$ is supposed to kronecker delta with $ij$ as indexes.

1. $(d_{il}d_{jm} - d_{im}d_{jl})a_jb_lc_m$
2. $(d_{kl}d_{im} - d_{km}d_{il})A_lC_mB_k$

I simply cant understand how I'm supposed to think, I thought $d_{il}A_l = A_i$.

Sorry for extremely hard to read, hopefully someone can help me, I cant understand how the two results works together. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it comes from Einstein notation we summate over paired subscripts. For kronecker symbol we have that $d_{ij}=1$ if $i=j$ and equal to $0$ otherwise.

Thus, in application to the first expression:

$$
(d_{il}d_{jm} - d_{im}d_{jl})a_jb_lc_m=(d_{il}d_{jm}a_jb_lc_m)-(d_{im}d_{jl}a_jb_lc_m)
$$
For the first term we take $m=j$, for the second $l=j$
$$
(d_{il}a_jb_lc_j)-(d_{im}a_jb_jc_m)$$
Now $l=i$ and $m=i$ respectively, which leads to 
$$a_jb_ic_j-a_jb_jc_i$$

Calculations for the second expression pretty much the same

Comment: ahh, I think I understand what you mean, gonna try to calculate some on my own, will come back if I get into more trouble, thank you!